# Porque al hacer una suma en un string me lo hace en ASCII

Tags: c

Muy buenas. Me encuentro con un ejercicio en el que hay que leer unos números de un fichero *txt* y luego sumarlos, pero a la hora de sumarlos me los suma mal. Hice una comprobación y los números me los lee bien , pero a la hora de sumarlos me los suma con ASCII. Les dejo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main() {
    FILE *f1;
    int suma = 0, i;
    f1 = fopen("C:\\hola.txt", "r");
    char linea[10];
    while (fgets(linea, 10, (FILE*) f1)) {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (linea[i] != ' ') {
                suma = suma + linea[i];
                printf("%c ", linea[i]);
                printf("%i\n", suma);
            }
        }
        if (f1 == NULL) {
            printf("error");
        }
        printf("%i",suma);
    }
    fclose(f1);
}
```

Comment: Estás sumando elementos traídos de un array de char. Cada elemento es un char. Para poder hacer esa suma, el compilador va a usar el valor numérico que tiene a la mano. Ese valor es el código ASCII. Haz la conversión (_casting_) del char de forma explícita... el compilador hace lo que puede pero estás suponiendo que te lee la mente :)

Comment: PD. char != string

Comment: Gracias , con que comando puedo hacer la conversion

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que convertir explícitamente el char en entero (hacer *casting*). Como te dije en comentarios, es necesario indicarle al compilador que no use el número de un char (la representación ASCII) sino su contenido.

Para ir de char a int, funciona bien hacer:

```
char a = '4';
int ia = a - '0';
```

Donde esa resta logra que, al valor ASCII del caracter numérico se le reste el valor ASCII del caracter cero. **Sólo funcionará con números de un dígito, se asume que sólo necesitas char**

Aquí va un ejemplo simplificado con tu código que probé en https://cplayground.com/ :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    //FILE *f1;
    int suma=0, i, j=0;
    //f1=fopen("C:\\hola.txt","r");
    char linea[10] = {'1', '2', '3', ' ', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1'};
    while(j < 3) {
        for(i=0; i<10; i++){
            if(linea[i] != ' '){
                suma = suma + (linea[i] - '0');
                printf("%c ", linea[i] );
                printf("%i\n",suma);
            }
        }
        /*if(f1==NULL){
            printf("error");
        }*/
        printf("%i", suma);
    
        j++;
    }
    
    // fclose(f1);
}
```

Usando [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5030086/236345) como guía.